# Run a 32-bit binary on Google Cloud Run

Tags: google-cloud-platform, 64-bit, 32-bit, binary

The title say it all. I need a way to run a 32-bit binary on Cloud Run, which [seems to only support 64-bit](https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/reference/container-contract#:%7E:text=Executables%20in%20the%20container%20image%20must%20be%20compiled%20for%20Linux%2064-bit)

What I'm looking for is some sort of emulator or compatibility layer that I could install.

I cannot compile the program to 64-bits.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the program I was looking for, which is [qemu](https://www.qemu.org/docs/master/user/main.html).

After you add `apt install -y qemu-user` to your Dockerfile you can run a 32-bit binary with the command `qemu-i386 ./file`

I hope one day someone comes across this question & answer and finds it useful.

Comment: 1) Did you verify that this works in Cloud Run? 2) Your solution is interesting. QEMU is a well know program that has been around for a long time. I would like to see the Cloud Run Dockerfile that supports this with a real working example. That would make your answer useful in the future.

Comment: @JohnHanley 1) I did verify it. 2) I might update the anwser with a minimal example, but right now it is used in a complex closed-source program, so currently I cannot present that to you as an example. Altough I think that what I've provided is enough for someone to get started.

Comment: I was able to make this work very well. The key lines from the Dockerfile are below. This uses Ubuntu, not Alpine.

FROM python:3.10-slim
dpkg --add-architecture i386
apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends libc6:i386

Comment: Correction - the key lines from the Dockerfile are below. You may need additional packages if you have a C++ app - this is for a C app.

FROM ubuntu:18.04
dpkg --add-architecture i386
apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends qemu-user libc6:i386

Then, to run the 32-bit application:
qemu-i386 /path/to/myapp